# Reference for Linux API like MSDN?

Tags: c++, c, linux, api

Is there any nice to read Linux API reference like the one offered by MSDN or boost? I like the detailed information about the parameters from MSDN and the pre- an post conditions from the boost documentation. But until now I found nothing comparable in the net for Linux.

Comment: type "man" into the console

Comment: [`man`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page)

Comment: [The Linux Programming Interface](http://www.amazon.com/The-Linux-Programming-Interface-Handbook/dp/1593272200/)

Comment: Die dot net is a terrible outdated resource that fools google with a good SEO. Don't use it. Use kernel.org.

Comment: I don't know MSDN, does it include a kernel interface that allows people to do things like Linux kernel modules? (kernel interaction withoutsystem calls)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read first good books like [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (you can download it) and [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup)

Be aware that GNU/Linux is by definition less monolithic than Windows (because many contributors are working on it, and) because it is made of many independent programs.

<sup>Therefore, there is no well defined Linux API (except for the kernel syscalls; but GNU/Linux is more than the kernel)</sup>

Of course, read the man pages, in particular start with the [intro(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/intro.2.html) man page about [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) and other [man-pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/).

Be aware that Linux is nearly implementing (a superset of) the [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix) standard specification from the [OpenGroup](http://www.opengroup.org/).

Read also many good documentations from [TLDP](http://tldp.org/).

If you are interested by desktop application development, understand first what 
[X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) is, (beware, X11 is very complex in the details). Then read documentation from [freedesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/). Better yet, learn to use a graphical toolkit like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) or [Gtk](http://gtk.org/)

And GNU/Linux is made of [**free software**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), you can download and **study the source code** and improve it. You'll very often use some existing free software library, and you may study its source code (and each of them has its own documentation). Part of your work is finding good free software related to your needs. [freecode](http://freecode.com/) and [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) are good resources (and they are many others).

Answer (score 15):

The man pages are definitely a good start, as others have noted. If you'd like something more formal and rigorous, however, I would recommend reading the POSIX specification. Here is the index of functions in the standard:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/contents.html

Looking at what the standard requires, rather than what the current implementations of these functions on Linux happen to do, will also help you write more portable, robust software.

Comment: This is overkill for my concerns but nice to know where to find detailed information. Bookmarked. Thanks.

Comment: @cirosantilli: I get your objection, but it really depends on what OP means by "Linux". If the intended meaning is "one of the common operating systems, aka 'distributions', using the Linux kernel" then I believe my answer is reasonable. If on the other hand OP were asking for the actual *Linux API* in the sense of Linux the kernel, then you're right; the syscall API itself is similar to but does not actually match POSIX, and the internal API is not even defined/stable from one kernel version to the next.

Comment: The man pages are IMHO the way to go - everything is documented there  in great detail. They are part of whatever distro you work on thus they are up to date with the kernel / glibc you use. And they do not only cover PARTS of the linux API (like the POSIX specs - which version BTW?) but ALL of the API. Many parts of the API are only available if you define appropriate C Preprocessor Variables. The man pages list all of those requirements as well.

Comment: @MichaelBeer: I would say both are really useful. I find the man pages lacking sufficient precision to know what's guaranteed in corner cases and to know what's portable vs Linux-specific or glibc-specific usage, but they're also easier to understand and cover more material (not just the standard interfaces, the extensions too) and have good examples.

Answer (score 3):

I have this bookmarked.

[The Linux man-pages project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/)